# why is table.remove and in pairs function both not working in Roblox Studio?

Tags: parsing, lua-table

I have the following code which Roblox Developer and the Lua.org manual both say should work to remove an instance from the table so I can store as a local, but the local is only holding a nil value.

The table is there. It shows up on the print function. It just will not store to be useful in the app.

I have tried multiple versions of this code including going with just the pairs function, just the table.remove function, and going with and without the position for the table remove, and it all generates nil variable.

```
    
        response = HttpService:GetAsync(mining)
        data = HttpService:JSONDecode(response, Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationJson)   
    
local function tprint(t)
        for k,v in pairs(t)  do print(k,v) end 
    end
    tprint(data)
    
    
    local a = table.remove(data, 4)
    local b = table.remove(data, 3)
    local c = table.remove(data, 2)
    local d = table.remove(data, 1)
```

Comment: This is the table I am trying to draw from. What I want in a local value is the 1. Every which way I have tried, it comes back as nil or value, but never as 1. ["result"] =  ▼  {
                       ["amount"] = 1,
                       ["depositAddress"] = "DQ2DPUoSZti4nJ2ms882ABn8

Comment: Does the fact that it is an embedded table change how the positions are coded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being so simple, and yet so profound. I can now use this to link crypto, bank accounts, credit cards, and anything else I want directly into Roblox or any other lua based program.

```
a = (data["result"]["amount"])
```

Comment: Heyo, just a heads up, be careful around using crypto or selling things off platform to impact in game experiences on Roblox. The [Roblox Community Guidelines](https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203313410-Roblox-Community-Standards) forbid this kind of thing (see Section 30).

Answer (score 0):

Before I dig into the error you're seeing, first some background information.

Lua tables have two methods of indexing values: numerically, and by keys. Often times you will see these two different methods be used to describe the kind of data structure that uses it.

Arrays and lists are tables that use numeric keys to index information.

```
local arr = {}
arr[1] = "abc"
arr[2] = 123
arr[3] = true

-- print the length of the array
print(#arr) -- 3

-- print the contents of the array
for i, v in ipairs(arr) do
    print(i, v)
    -- 1 abc
    -- 2 123
    -- 3 true
end
```

On the other side of things, dictionaries and hash maps and associative arrays use keys to store information :

```
local dict = {}
dict["foo"] = "abc"
dict["bar"] = 123
dict["blah"] = true
dict["katz"] = { 1, 2, 3 }

-- print the number of numerical keys in the dictionary
print(#dict) -- 0

-- print the contents of the dictionary
for k, v in pairs(dict) do
    print(k, v)
    -- foo abc
    -- bar 123
    -- blah true
    -- katz table
end
```

While lua allows a table to use both of these indexing methods simultaneously, it's important never to mix the two, as behaviors can get real funky when you do. When a table has keys, treat it like a dictionary. When a table has numerical indices, treat it like an array.

When you use HttpService to decode a JSON string into a table, it generates a dictionary that reflects the heirarchical structure of the original data.

The [table](https://www.lua.org/pil/19.2.html) library, which you call with `table.insert()` and `table.remove()` expects that the table you're working with is an array.

When your data is arranged like this :

```
local data = {}
data["Success"] = true
data["StatusCode"] = 200
data["StatusMessage"] = "Success"
data["Headers"] = {} -- a dictionary of headers
data["Body"] = {
    result = {
        amount = 1,
        depositAddress = "blah",
    },
} -- after HttpService:JSONDecode() is called...
```

And you tell it to remove a numbered index with `table.remove(data, 4)`, it won't work because there's no data stored at index number 4. `data` is a dictionary, not an array.

Often, it is annoying to try to print out the contents of a table with multiple layers of data, especially JSON tables, as the `pairs` function will only index one level at a time. Thankfully, Roblox's `print` function and Output widget are smart enough to do this for you. You can simply `print(data)` and it will show you the full table in the output and allow you to inspect each level.

Then once you know how your data is structured you can step through it value by value.

```
local amount = data["Body"]["result"]["amount"]
-- or
local amount = data.Body.result.amount
```